# Does Python still print a trailing newline after printing the contents of a file?

Tags: python, file, file-read, trailing-newline

***Disclaimer***: I know I essentially answer my own question, but please humor me anyway.

I'm working through a Python book I have (*Python Crash Course 2nd Edition*), and it says, "The only difference between this output and the original file is the extra blank line at the end of the output. The blank line appears because read() returns an empty string when it reaches the end of the file; this empty string shows up as blank line. If you want to remove the extra blank line, you can use rstrip() in the call to print()." That is the exact wording they use in the book. However, when I do what they tell me to do, no blank line is printed.

All of my code:

```
with open('/workspaces/functions/files_exceptions/pi_digits.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()

print(contents)
print("Hello World!") # To show a newline is not printed
```

Everything in the file I'm reading from:

```
 3.1415926535
      8979323846
      2643383279
```

Output:

```
3.1415926535
  8979323846
  2643383279
Hello World!
```

The output the book shows (the underlines are meant to represent a blank line (Stack Overflow won't let me include a blank line as code)):

```
3.1415926535
  8979323846
  2643383279
____________
```

As you can see, there is no trailing newline printed by Python. Does it not do this anymore? I know Python is now in version 3.12, so I'm wondering if it's a recent change made to Python. It might not be though, because the VS Code repo I'm working in was created before the update (I don't know whether or not it updates automatically, or if you have to do it manually (and if so, how) (please tell me the answer to this)).

Comment: It sounds to me like what the book is saying is being said in some other context. For example in the context of reading a file little by little in a `while` loop. In this context, the last read from the file would return an empty string, and if you `print`ed that empty string, that would of course result in a blank line (because `print` adds a newline after every output).

Comment: If your file does *not* end with a newline after the last `…279`, then this code demonstrates that `print` *does* add a newline. Otherwise you'd see `…279Hello World!`.

Comment: @deceze, doesn't Python not work that way? If you print() two things in a row, they won't be on the same line, they'll be on separate ones. Unless you're saying that that's what newline does? But doesn't newline put a space in-between print statements, not make it so that they're not on the same line?

Comment: `print` by default adds a newline after the printed content. If you `print` an empty string (`print('')`), you'll see an empty string followed by a newline. Which of course looks like a blank line.

Comment: Yeah, based on deceze's comments, I think I answered too fast without carefully reading your original message.
"The only difference between this output between this file and the original file is the extra blank line at the end of the output."
I think we can't accurately answer this question without knowing what the two files in question are referring to.

Comment: @CooperHarasyn, what do you mean by what the two files are referring to? Do you mean what their contents are? I put all of the contents of both files in the question.

Comment: "The only difference between this output between this file and the original file"

What is "this file" and "the original file"? Two text files, or different Python scripts?

Comment: The crucial part of the information here would be whether the files contain a newline at the end. Which posting their text here we can't tell.

Comment: *"All of my code"* — But is that also the code the book used?

Comment: @deceze, yes it is. And the .txt file doesn't contain a newline at the end.

Comment: If the file _doesn't_ contain a newline at the end, then the output is exactly as expected. `print` is adding a newline after it. Otherwise you'd see `Hello World!` on the same line.

Comment: @deceze, I edited the question and added what the book shows as the expected output. Could you take a look at it please? I get a different output from the one in the book, even though the book and I use the same code.

Comment: @CooperHarasyn, I accidentally misquoted the passage. The actual quote is, "The only difference between this output and the original file...." And to answer your question, the "original file" is the .txt file with the pi digits in it, and "this output" is the output we get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256325/discussion-between-not-a-mimic-and-deceze).

Comment: @SlightlyPsychotic I emailed the author. He kindly explained to me that the behaviour depends on the setup, some setups print a blank line at the end and some don't . I think that for beginners it might be better to just take note of what it does in one's setup and continue without wasting too much more time and effort on that.

Comment: @Santropedro Oh, ok. Thanks for your help and initiative!

Answer (score 3):

You are conflating, I think, the default result of `print` with what is happening with `file.read()`. The `\n` is added by `print` and not by reading the file.

Even if you print a null string, print as a default adds a `\n` at the end:

```
>>> print("")

>>>
```

vs:

```
>>> print("something")
something
>>>
```

If you read an entire file into a string, that is read and then `print` adds that same `\n`. Your code is reading the whole contents of the file in one read. No `\n` is added (or ever was added) by Python's `.read()` method.

You can [override](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) the terminating `\n` for `print` in Python 3 (or with the `print` function in Python 2):

```
>>> print("something",end="!")
something!>>>
```

But the default is `\n`.

Contrast this with `file.write` for stream output where a `\n` is NOT added at the end. This is important to know since a Unix file should be terminated with a `\n` to not break certain utilities...

---

With several edits of the post, maybe an example is helpful.

First, create a file as I understand what you have:

```
fn='/tmp/file.txt'

string='''\
 3.1415926535
      8979323846
      2643383279'''  # Note no trailing \n
        
with open(fn, 'w') as f:
    f.write(string)
```

Now read that file and print the `repr` of it which shows the acutual `\n` that were read:

```
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    input_string=f.read()    # read entire file as a string
    print(repr(input_string))
```

That prints:

```
' 3.1415926535\n      8979323846\n      2643383279'
```

So you can see that no new line is added by `.read` at the end.

If you just print that string and then another line of output:

```
print(input_string); print('on a new line')
```

Your output is replicated:

```
 3.1415926535
      8979323846
      2643383279
on a new line
```

Contrast with:

```
print(input_string, 'NOT on a new line')
```

Where there is NOT a `\n` inserted:

```
 3.1415926535
      8979323846
      2643383279 NOT on a new line
```

Instead, the print `sep` property of `print` is used which, default, is a space.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the book which you're quoting is correct. Whether or not `f.read()` has a newline character at the end of the string which it returns is dependent on the contents of the file which is being read. Many text editors will add newlines at the end of text files, even if the user does not input them manually. I also use Visual Studio Code and my experience is that it does not enforce newlines at the end of files, so I think that a difference in editor or editor settings is the most likely explanation for your difference in behaviour.

Observe the following test, in which I use `echo -n` to create a file without a newline at the end, and `echo` to create a file with a newline at the end:

```
WSL /tmp/python-test$ echo -n "Test with no newline at the end" > no-newline.txt
WSL /tmp/python-test$ echo "Test with newline at the end" > newline.txt
WSL /tmp/python-test$ cat test.py
with open('no-newline.txt') as f:
  textWithoutNewline = f.read()
with open('newline.txt') as f:
  textWithNewline = f.read()

print('=' * 10)
print(textWithoutNewline)
print('=' * 10)
print(textWithNewline)
print('=' * 10)
WSL /tmp/python-test$ python3 test.py
==========
Test with no newline at the end
==========
Test with newline at the end

==========
WSL /tmp/python-test$
```

Comment: Note that the book supposedly says *"read() returns an empty string"*, and does not claim that `read` returns a newline!

Comment: @CooperHarasyn, oh yeah, I think that's it. The book assumes that you're using Sublime Text as an IDE, but I switched over because A) VS has a way better dark theme and B) Sublime doesn't allow user input.